# How to display an image from inside an archive without extracting the archive

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a beginner with C# and WPF.

I have an archive file, Ex: Jonah Hex #18.cbz.  That archive contains images (ex: p0001.jpg, p0002.jpg, etc.).  I'm trying to display those images in a wpf application without extracting the archive.  I'm using the SharpCompress library to read through the archive and then trying to use a ValueConverter the string to bitmap image

I'm not able to get the images to display. Not sure if something is missing in the converter in xaml or something else.  Not getting any exceptions on the converter code

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Opens the archive using SharpCompress libary
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">Archive file</param>
        private void openArchive(string filename)
        {
            
                     // Opens the selected archive           
                    var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(filename);

                    // Loops through each file in the archive
                    foreach (IArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        // If the file is not comicinfo.xml 
                        if (entry.Key != "ComicInfo.xml")
                        {
                            // Adds the file names with extension found in archive to an observableCollection<BookPages> 
                            _bookPage.Add(new BookPages() { Pages = entry.Key });
                        }
                    }
```

Value Converter :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Assigns the value obtained by the Binding source to a path
            var path = (string)value;

            // Creates a byte[] array from the value of the path
            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);

            // If the path is empty
            if (path == null)
                //Returns nothing
                return null;

            // Creates the MemoryStream
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                //Creates the new BitmapImage
                var myImage = new BitmapImage();
                               
                    // Initializes the BitmapImage                
                    myImage.BeginInit();

                // Source of the image from the stream
                    myImage.StreamSource = stream;
                // Sets the CacheOption to OnDemand
                    myImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;
                    // Delays the creation until needed
                    myImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
                    // Sets the Width
                    myImage.DecodePixelWidth = 92;
                    // Sets the Height
                    myImage.DecodePixelHeight = 128;
                   
                    // Ends the initialization
                    myImage.EndInit();
                
                // returns the BitmapImage
                return myImage;
            }
        }
```

XAML :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BookPage}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                        <!-- Images bound to the pages -->
                        <Image Source="{Binding Pages, Converter={StaticResource StringToImage}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: `entry.ToString()` is of course not a valid image URI. You need to assign an appropriate Stream to the BitmapImage's `StreamSource` property (and also set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` before closing the Stream). With ZipStream it was also necessary to copy to a MemoryStream first, if I remember it correctly.

Comment: Changed the code to include a ValueConverter from String to Bitmapimage and used a Memorystream but still not able to get the images to display. See updated code above.  Not sure if the issue is with the converter or the BitmapImage not getting created properly

Comment: `Creates a byte[] array from the value of the path` - that makes no sense. You can not decode a bitmap from a string that contains its file name or path. The source property of the Binding should be an encoded bitmap frame, e.g. PNG or JPEG. Besides that, when you close a BitmapImage's StreamSource immediately after EndInit, you must set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe I found a possible solution to my problem.

I do have to convert the entry into a bitmap first and then use the stream to transfer it to a bitmap image.

The Image does display now.

```
using ComicSort.Core;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Prism.Commands;
using SharpCompress.Archives;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ComicSort.UI.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Private Members

        private string _title = "ComicSort";


        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> _thumbnail;
        public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Thumbnail
        {
            get { return _thumbnail; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _thumbnail, value); }
        }

        private BitmapImage _thumb;
        public BitmapImage Thumb
        {
            get { return _thumb; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _thumb, value); }
        }


        #endregion

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _thumbnail = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
        }

        private DelegateCommand _selectFileCommand;


        public DelegateCommand SelectFileCommand =>
            _selectFileCommand ?? (_selectFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSelectFileCommand));

        void ExecuteSelectFileCommand()
        {
            SelectFile();
        }

        private void SelectFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog.Filter = "CBZ files (*.cbz)|*.cbz|CBR files (*.cbr)|*.cbr|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            Nullable<bool> result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
                OpenArchive(filename);

            }

        }



        private void OpenArchive(string filename)
        {

            var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(filename);
            foreach (IArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (!entry.IsDirectory)
                {
                    if (entry.Key != "ComicInfo.xml")
                    {

                        Bitmap bitmap = LoadImage(entry);
                        DisplayImage(bitmap);

                    }

                }
            }

        }

        private void DisplayImage(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();


            image.BeginInit();
            image.StreamSource = ms;
            image.DecodePixelHeight = 128;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;
            image.EndInit();

            Thumb = image;

            }

        private Bitmap LoadImage(IArchiveEntry fileEntry)
        {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(fileEntry.OpenEntryStream());
            return bitmap;
        }


    }
}
```